# Subfolder .htacess not overriding parent .htacess options

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have an .htacess on the root of my domain to redirect all traffic to index.php

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#redirect http to https, remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#remove index.php from link
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] 

#redirect to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

</IfModule>

#remove direct access to all *.php except index.php
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Everything works as expected, traffic is redirect, when files exists show file.

now i have an admin folder /admin/ with and index.php and api.php
i can open the /admin/ and /admin/index.php but the /admin/api.php redirects to /index.php

i tried to put an .htaccess inside the /admin/ like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteEngine On

#redirect http to https, remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

but getting the same results. /admin/ opens, but /admin/api.php redirects to index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem/solution.

needed to add to the .htaccess inside the /admin/

```
 <Files *>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this has nothing to do with the issue you reported. The actual issue you have is that the config in the root folder is evaluated _first_ and redirects everything to a _relative_ path `index.php`, so the index file inside the folder that was requested. That is why also the request to `/admin/api.php` is redireted to `/admin/index.php`.